# Call AsyncTask after Timer runs out

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I understand that making the main UI thread wait is really a very bad idea as it leads to "Application Not Responding" message.

But here is my scenario.

I am making a call to my server from my android application in which I am sending the coordinates of the user, which the server uses to return the result accordingly.
The problem is that during the **first run** of the application, it takes a really long time to get the location. I am looking for both GPS and NETWORK providers to retrieve the location, and I run a 20 second timer before the fetch the location from both GPS and NETWORK providers.

Here is my class to find the Location of the user.

```
public class MyLocation {
    Timer timer1;
    LocationManager lm;
    LocationResult locationResult;
    boolean gps_enabled=false;
    boolean network_enabled=false;

    public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result)
    {
        //use LocationResult callback class to pass location value from MyLocation to user code.
        locationResult=result;
        if(lm==null)
            lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
        try{gps_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}
        try{network_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}

        //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
        if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
            return false;

        if(gps_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
        if(network_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
        timer1=new Timer();
        timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 20000); 
        return true;
    }

    LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

            Location net_loc=null, gps_loc=null;
            if(gps_enabled)
                gps_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if(network_enabled)
                net_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            //if there are both values use the latest one
            if(gps_loc!=null && net_loc!=null){
                if(gps_loc.getTime()>net_loc.getTime())
                    locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                else
                    locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                return;
            }

            if(gps_loc!=null){
                locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                return;
            }
            if(net_loc!=null){
                locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                return;
            }
            locationResult.gotLocation(null);
        }
    }

    public void cancelTimer() { 
        timer1.cancel();
        lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
        lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork); 
    }

    public static abstract class LocationResult{
        public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
    }
}
```

And in my Main Activity,

```
onCreate(...)
{
.
.
.
.
myLocation.getLocation(context, locationResult); // my call to the MyLocation class to get the user location

sendRequestToServer(); // calls an AsyncTask which uses the coordinates returned by the MyLocation class

}
```

**`getLocation(context, locationResult)`** passes the context to the MyLocation class and the result is stored in the `LocationResult callback class`.

So, in my Main Activity, I have

```
LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult(){
        @Override
        public void gotLocation(Location location){
            if(location != null)
            {
                mUser.setLastKnownLoc(location);
                Log.d("UserLocation", location.getLatitude() + "   "  + location.getLongitude());

            }
        }
    };
```

And my request to the server makes use of `mUser.getLastKnownLoc()` to get the value of the location stored in the result.

**My problem :** Making the sendRequestToServer() wait until I have the location

**What I tried :**

- Putting `myLocation.getLocation(..)` inside `doInBackground()` of an AsyncTask and calling `sendRequestToServer()` onPostExecute(), but still the sendRequestToServer would not wait for the timer in MyLocation class to finish.
- Creating another timer inside onCreate and setting `mTimer.schedule(RequestToserver,20000)` so that sendRequestToServer is called only after 20 secs(by the time the other timer in MyLocation finsihes). This seemed to work a bit as the request was made only after 20 secs, but then my application would crash due to some thread handling problems. I tried to run the timerTask on the UIThread and attached Looper.prepare() to it. But I got caught up in a vicious cycle of thread handling errors, propably due to the fact that `sendRequestToServer()` calls an AsyncTask which again has it's own background thread.

I have been trying to get this work for quite some time now.  I just need to make sure that the AsyncTask is called after the 20 sec MyLocation timer runs out.

Any help/suggestion from your side would be really great!!

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question, but why don't you make the call to the server in the gotLocation callback?

Comment: I cant believe it never occured to me! Sounds good enough to me! Should work! Let me try it out and get back to you! Thanks a lot @Ryan!

Comment: @Ryan : It did work, *partially*. I mean, now the call to the server is made only after the location is received. But I am not being to change the visibility of the ui elements. Throws me an error that `only the thread which created the views can touch it`. Any ideas on how to fix that ?

Comment: @Ryan : I did it I did it!!! :D Your idea totally worked for me!Thanks a tonne!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your onCreate just show a `ProgressDialog` which blocks user input, run your getLocation in the background and when it gets a location just dismiss the `ProgressDialog` and start your new `AsyncTask` to send the data.

Like.

```
ProgressDialog pd = ...;
pd.show();
MyLocation ml = new MyLocation(new LocationResultsCallback(){ 
    public void onLocationRecieved(Location loc){
        //must run on UI thread
        pd.dismiss();
        new SendResultsTask(loc).execute();
    }
});
ml.findLocation(); // start location finding
```

Also for your getLastKnownLocation it might be better to switch it to something like this.

```
String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);
if(bestProvider!=null)
    Location local = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
```

That is if this is applicable, I dont know what restrictions you have on location providers.

Also instead of Timer, it is more proper to use a Handler, but both should work in you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It never occurred to me that I should be making the request to the server in the callback class. And after that there were some problems in accessing the ViewHierarchy, which got removed after I called the AsyncTask in a `runOnUiThread`. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Right thats why i said //must run on UI thread, because only the UI thread can access views(like the progress dialog). But np, glad you got it!

Comment: `LocationResult locationResultStartup = new LocationResult(){
  @Override
  public void gotLocation(Location location){
   if(location != null)
   {
    mUser.setLastKnownLoc(location);
    Log.d("UserLocationStartup", location.getLatitude() + "   "  + location.getLongitude());
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
      checkFbLogin();
     }
    });

   }
  }
 };`

Comment: Sir, just have a look at the code I posted in the comment. I hope I am doing it the right way. Dont want to come up with problems later.

Comment: And my `checkFbLogin()` sends makes a call to the server and also changes the visibility of a few UI elements in the layout.

Comment: Well what i would do is every one of these background tasks i would run in an ASyncTask. For example the locationLookup you run that in an ASyncTask and then in the onPostExecute(which runs on the UI thread) call your callback. Then from that callback do your UI stuff, and then call your other AsyncTasks as needed in progression. You shouldn't need to do runOnUiThread, tho thats not necessarily bad to do so, just should not be needed..

Comment: Yes, sir! I totally get your point. Actually, if you see my question again, that is the first thing I tried. I put getLocation in doInBackground and then I put checkFbLogin() in onPostEXecute(). The problem was checkFbLogin() would be called even before the location was received. So, actually it was of no use. Did I do something wrong ? And what exactly do you mean by **call your callback** ? Do you mean the checkFbLogin() function which sends the request to the server ? Or do u mean to tweak my LocationResult class(the code that I posted in my above comment) ?

Answer (score 1):

this is stupid solution sometimes work.anyway try to use it

boolean x=......get location();

so that it waits for result x.put this in oncreate() if needed .if problem exist post back

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the thing is that getLocation() stores the result in a callback variable, `locationResult`. Can I still do it ?

Comment: Have added the code of the callback class in my question. Kindly have a look. I am totally out of ideas regarding this.

Comment: And if I do `boolean x = ...getLocation()`, do I need to check the value of x before making a call to the server ? Something like, `while (!x) {//do nothing and wait}` ? As in do I need to keep on checking the value of x again and again and wait for it to become true before I make the call to the server ? or does it happen automatically ?

Comment: I fixed it! By invoking the call to the server inside the callback class. Anyway, thanks for your help! :)

Comment: And +1 for really appreciating your help! Thanks! :)